# Function does not re-render when clicking button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple react counter, where on click INC button the value should change the value inside h1. But it is not working.

My code in App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let count = 0;

  function handleInc () {
    return count++;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>{count}</h1>

        <div className='container'>
        <button onClick={handleInc}>INC</button>
        <button>DEC</button>
        <button>RESET</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Can you please tell me what the error is?

Comment: Check react class based components / useState hook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)! On each click, this method will tell react to re-render this component and any children, thus displaying the updated counter to the dom.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function handleInc () {
    return setCount(count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>{count}</h1>

        <div className='container'>
        <button onClick={handleInc}>INC</button>
        <button>DEC</button>
        <button>RESET</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

Comment: `useState` returns an `array` of 2 elements, some would call this a tuple. I am using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull the first and second elements out, into variables `count`, this is your state and `setCount`, a function that will update `count`. When `setCount` is called, this will tell React to re-render your component.

Comment: I didn't realize I was that noob at that time! Thanks, @DanStarns